# jquery slideshow stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I've created a jQuery canvas slideshow to apply image an filter while running the slideshow.  Everything seems to be working fine, but when I apply the filter to the image, the slideshow doesn't load other slides and keeps loading the same slide.

To have a look at the problem follow the link:

http://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~0819487/MySlider/mySlider.html

Any help you guys could give would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pixastic is replacing your `#canvas`element when you apply a filter. So your `canvas` and `context` variables are refering to an object that is no longer in the page. Basically you need to reset those two variables after applying a filter.

For the simplest fix, you need to replace `context` with `document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")`  in your `drawImg` method. This will keep the images rotating. But the filter will no longer be applied after the image change. For that you'd need to call the relevant filter function after drawing the reassigned the image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked but after the slide transition screen brightness were decreased so I made li'l bit change to make it work properly.

`drawImg = function(src){

    jQuery('#canvas').fadeOut(500,function(){

        img.src = src;

        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.drawImage(img, posX, posY);

        if (jQuery('#canvas').is(":hidden")){

            jQuery('#canvas').fadeIn(500);

            polarize();

        }

    });

}`

Thanks again for ur help I was really stuck in this, Now I got another question if u could help me in that, Which is about persistance of filtered images like I want to overwrite the same image with filtered image.

Regards

Comment: If you go that route, wouldn't you need to keep a copy of each image with each filter applied?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to apply the selected filter after each image rotation?

Comment: Yes i want to keep each image with filter applied, actually I want replace the original images with filter applied images in the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just using something like [the Nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) which is really expansive in its features and well supported?